# Borders between column groups in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix in SSRS with multiple column groupings. I'd like to put a border between the major grouping that is different than the minor grouping.

For example:

```
            -----------------------------------------------------
           | Group 1                  | Group 2                  |
            -----------------------------------------------------
           | Sub 1    Sub 2    Sub 3  | Sub 1    Sub 2    Sub 3  |
            -----------------------------------------------------
Row 1      |    10       20       30  |    10       20       30  |
Row 2      |    40       50       60  |    40       50       60  |
            -----------------------------------------------------
```

Above, there is only a border around the major group (Group 1, 2) and not around the minor groups (sub 1, 2, 3)

Any recommendations on how I might accomplish this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What would be easiest would be to just add a subtotal column for your parent group, then make it zero width with an appropriate vertical border.

Alternatively, if you do not have null values in your table you can set an individual border style to a simple expression.  From the properties pane, expand the "BorderStyle" property and set the left border to an expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!SubGroup.Value=First(Fields!SubGroup.Value,"SubGroup"),"Solid","None")
```

Substituting your actual field names where appropriate.  For reference, that property is set here:

[image: BorderStyle Expression]

Comment: Thanks - I'll try the subtotal column. However, I'm attempting to add vertical borders versus horizontal borders.

Comment: Oops - that is very much what I meant, as adding horizontal borders to a column would indeed be of very limited use.